# Run command when bash script is stopped

Tags: bash, macos

How can i, in a bash script, execute a command when the user stops the script (with ctrl - c)?

Currently, i have this:

```
afplay file.mp3

while true:
do osascript -e "set volume 10"
end
```

But i would like it to execute `killall afplay` when the user is finished with it, regardless if it is command-c or another keypress.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`trap 'killall afplay' EXIT`

Answer (score 4):

Use `trap`.

```
trap "kill $pid" INT TERM EXIT
```

Also avoid `killall` or `pkill`, since it could kill unrelated processes (for instance, from another instance of your script, or even a different script). Instead, put the player's PID in a variable and kill only that PID.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for grabbing the pid of a process? (I imagine it being straight forward if the process is started locally)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `trap` statement in your bash script:

```
trap 'killall afplay' EXIT
```

Note however that this won't work if the bash process is sent a `KILL` signal (9) as it's not possible for processes to intercept that signal.